# Truncating y axis in matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

The y axis of my matplotlib bar chart is between 0 and 1. However, all values for in the chart are between 0.8 and 1 so I would like to start the y axis at 0.7. I haven't been able to find the pandas method of doing this so any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If using `DataFrame.plot()` method, add argument `ylim=(0.7, 1)`

Comment: yep that worked perfectly thanks. I did not know lim existed

Answer (score 2):

### New Answer

@ChrisA has provided the best answer in the comments: **If using `DataFrame.plot()` method, add argument `ylim=(0.7, 1)`**

### Old Answer

If you've used the usual `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`, a quick fix could be to add the following lines under your pandas plot command:

```
# gca = "get current axis"
ax = plt.gca()

# ax.get_ylim() returns a tuple of (lower ylim, upper ylim)
ax.set_ylim(0.7, ax.get_ylim()[1])
```

If you're using the object-oriented matplotlib API that typically starts with something like `fig, ax = plt.subplots()` (reference: [The Lifecycle of a Plot](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/introductory/lifecycle.html)), then you won't need to run `ax = plt.gca()`.